# Make map return Nothing if one of the elements producing Nothing

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to implement Huffman compression in Haskell for learning purposes. So far I can successfully create the correct tree for a given String and I can get the correct path to a character from a specific tree. The signature of that function is like this:

```
getPath :: HuffmanTree -> Char -> Maybe String
```

It returns a Just String where '0' represents the left and '1' the right branch. If the character isn't contained in the tree it returns Nothing. My next step is to pass it a whole String and turn it to an encoded String of 1s and 0s. The method should return Nothing, if one of the characters is not found in the tree, accordingly the function signature should look like this:

```
encode :: HuffmanTree -> String -> Maybe String
```

My current Method of doing this is like this:

```
encode tree str =
let encodings = map (\e -> getPath tree e) str
in
    if elem Nothing encodings
    then Nothing
    else
        let encodings' = map fromJust encodings
        in Just (foldl (++) "" encodings')
```

But this doesn't seem to be a very elegant way of solving this. I know, I can abort everything if the first getPath returns Nothing, so every evaluation after that is unnecessary. I feel like, there is a fancy monadic way to do this right, but I couldn't think of one and I don't really know what to search for. Or is this the right way and just let laziness take care of everything?

Comment: Share the details of the `HuffmanTree`.

Comment: Unrelated to you question, but remember that it's [almost never a good idea to use `foldl`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there's a monadic way for doing that, and it's not particularly fancy. This is *exactly* what the `Maybe` applicative is about, thus you can use [`traverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:traverse):

```
encode tree str = fmap concat $ traverse (\e -> getPath tree e) str
```

or short

```
encode tree = fmap concat . traverse (getPath tree)
```

Neat, eh?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work entirely. I get the error "Couldn't match type ‘[String]’ with ‘Maybe String’
      Expected type: String -> Maybe String
        Actual type: [Char] -> [String]". I don't know where the Maybe part gets lost?

Comment: Have you tried the current version or the first I posted (which didn't include `concat`)?

Comment: The current one. Without the concat i got the error, that he was expecting a single string, but got a list of strings. I got that, and as I was looking again you provided the new version

Comment: Oh, okay, I just tried the short version. The one without currying works just fine and dandy

Comment: Ah, right I made a mistake in the short version.

Comment: Works like a charm now. Have my thanks, humble programmer ^^

Comment: Note `mapM` is a specialisation of `traverse` for Monads like `Maybe`. When I had the same question as in the title, I overlooked this solution at first thinking it was specific to details in the question, and eventually came up with `concat <$> mapM myElementToMaybeStringFunc elems` instead. I came back to announce my triumph and realise it's exactly the solution described here!